# Printing a variable inside for loop, C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, cout

This is part of my code that calculates `xi` using a class `cosmology.xi_DM`.
I am very new to C++, so please bear with me!

```
double redshift = 0.75;
  string method = "CAMB";
  vector<double> r = {1., 2.};

  double xi = 0.;
  for (int i=0; i<r.size(); i++)
    xi = cosmology.xi_DM(r[i], method, redshift);

    cout << "xi_DM(z=" << redshift << ") = " << xi << endl;
```

However, when I `print` it, **I only get the value of `xi` for `r = 2.`. It does not print `xi` for `r = 1.`.** Why is this so?

Comment: Your `cout` is *outside* the `for` loop. If you want it *inside*, but `{` and `}` around the block of code to be in the `for` loop.

Comment: @MrLister: thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: You're used to Python, aren't you?

Comment: @MrLister Exactly!! I have never used C++ before!!

Comment: This should be covered by any good book, tutorial, or class instruction on C++. You should consider finding a resource to learn some of the basics.

Comment: @crashmstr As I had told you before, I am a complete beginner. I still don't understand why few people have downvoted my question. They would have started similarly!!

Comment: @user3397243 first link from google search of "C++ for loop" is [Statements and flow control](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/), which explains this in great detail. If you had searched first, you would have already found an answer. (In other words, Stack Overflow is a *great place* for questions, but prehaps not the *best place* for page one learning of a language).

Comment: Urgent read: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed brackets:

```
for (int i=0; i<r.size(); i++)
{
    xi = cosmology.xi_DM(r[i], method, redshift);

    cout << "xi_DM(z=" << redshift << ") = " << xi << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `cout << ...` instruction is **not** in the loop.

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<r.size(); i++)
{
    xi = cosmology.xi_DM(r[i], method, redshift);

    cout << "xi_DM(z=" << redshift << ") = " << xi << endl;
}
```